# Array.reduce changing initial object into current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reduce

When I try to reduce an array into an object, the value of the object keeps getting over written when I don't set the initial object to a variable outside the reduce function:

```
relevantGroupFiles.then(function(data) {
  var results = [];
  var rawResults = data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;
  rawResults = _.map(rawResults, function(x) { return x.Cells })

  var propertiesWanted = ['Path', 'Title', 'ccaApplicationFileNumber', 'created']

  rawResults.forEach(function(item) {
    var r = propertiesWanted.reduce(function(total, current) {
      return  total[current] = _.find(item, {"Key": current}).Value
    }, {})

    results.push(r)
  })
})
```

When I step through the code, the first iteration returns this:

`total = {Path: "somePath"}` which is good, then I want to add the next property.

But the very next iterations, total turns into this: `total = "somePath"`

Then I get an error because it's trying to set the next property on `somePath` which is no longer an object but a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return total...

```
    var r = propertiesWanted.reduce(function(total, current) {
       total[current] = _.find(item, {"Key": current}).Value;
       return total;
    }, {})
```

Comment: Ohhh I'm returning the set property, I see. Thank you.